# Injective vs. Bijective

Tags: functions

What's the difference between Injective and Bijective? For example, is there a more rigorous proof of the bijectivity of a function? Also, can these properties be applied to more than just functions? Thank you!

Comment: Critical question: is the mapping *onto* (AKA surjective)?

Comment: I also think it is important to point out the very useful fact that **every injection is a bijection over its image**. In this sense, the two concepts really have an intrinsic connection

Comment: @user2661923 what's the mathematical definition of surjective? I didn't learn all three together for some reason, though I know that's common. If it's easier for you than explaining in detail, you can just point me in the right direction (i.e. with links) and I'll figure it out myself from there. Thanks!

Comment: @Gauss Your comment reminds me of the "All squares are rectangles but not all rectangles are squares." statement. All bijections are injections but not all injections are bijections?

Comment: @Gauss what do you mean by image? I've heard the term before but never learned it in detail.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You ask "what is the difference between injective and bijective", but in the next sentence you ask for a more rigorous proof of the bijectivity of a function. You do not say which function is meant. And finally you ask "can these properties be applied to more than just functions". What is the meaning of *more* - which entities do you mean? I therefore voted to close your question.

Comment: @bjorn A bijection must satisfy two properties. 1) It must be injective and 2) it must be surjective. Wikipedia has a good breakdown on this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine you have some number of buckets and some number of balls. Your "mapping" is putting balls into buckets. Then the map is

- **surjective** if every bucket has *at least one* ball;
- **injective** if every bucket has *at most one* ball;
- **bijective** if every bucket has *exactly one* ball.